# std::find on an (unordered_)map

Tags: c++

For an unordered_map I have I want to do a reverse lookup (meaning to find the key given a value). One would expect this to be simple using std::find. I tried the following, which doesn't work:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int, int>    map;

    auto iter = std::find(map.begin(), map.end(), [](const std::pair<int, int> &pair) -> bool {
        return pair.second == 4;
    }); 
}
```

The compiler complains about an invalid binary expression, apparently it tries to compare the value to the predicate itself:

> /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/bits/predefined_ops.h:194:17: error: invalid operands to binary expression
>         ('std::pair' and 'const (lambda at unordered_map.cpp:8:51)')
>           { return *__it == _M_value; }

What am I missing here? As far as I know, this should be a valid predicate to search the map.

Comment: Did you mean `find_if`?

Comment: Using `std::find` with an `std::unordered_map` is almost certainly a mistake. Use `std::unordered_map::find`.

Comment: Btw, the problem aside, you should know you are examining copies of the pairs  in the map.

Comment: @PasserBy While I agree with the first part of that comment, the member `find` is not useful here because we are not performing a look-up based on the key.

Comment: @PasserBy That does the opposite of what the OP wants.  They are looking for a value, not a key

Comment: Oh, oops, I think I'm too tired to read properly :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `std::find` function is used to look for a *value* in the container. If you have a predicate you want to use then use `std::find_if`.

See e.g. [this `std::find` and `std::find_if` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).